# How to join two DataTable together with inner join

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, join

So I have 2 datatables that I want to merge into 1 in the same way that one merges with an inner join in sql server.

One catch is that some of the field names are the same in both tables, but the values may be different (eg. pricing values). The tables both have a column 'ID' that have the same value and can be joined.

Comment: Use fully qualified column names.

Comment: Post some actual table descriptions (columns, types etc.) and we can help you better.

Comment: See following webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    dt1.Columns.Add("CustID", typeof(int));
    dt1.Columns.Add("ColX", typeof(int));
    dt1.Columns.Add("ColY", typeof(int));

    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    dt2.Columns.Add("CustID", typeof(int));
    dt2.Columns.Add("ColZ", typeof(int));

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        DataRow row = dt1.NewRow();
        row["CustID"] = i;
        row["ColX"] = 10 + i;
        row["ColY"] = 20 + i;
        dt1.Rows.Add(row);

        row = dt2.NewRow();
        row["CustID"] = i;
        row["ColZ"] = 30 + i;
        dt2.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    var results = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                 join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on (int)table1["CustID"] equals (int)table2["CustID"]
                 select new
                 {
                     CustID = (int)table1["CustID"],
                     ColX = (int)table1["ColX"],
                     ColY = (int)table1["ColY"],
                     ColZ = (int)table2["ColZ"]
                 };
    foreach (var item in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("ID = {0}, ColX = {1}, ColY = {2}, ColZ = {3}", item.CustID, item.ColX, item.ColY, item.ColZ));
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

// Output:
// ID = 1, ColX = 11, ColY = 21, ColZ = 31
// ID = 2, ColX = 12, ColY = 22, ColZ = 32
// ID = 3, ColX = 13, ColY = 23, ColZ = 33
// ID = 4, ColX = 14, ColY = 24, ColZ = 34
// ID = 5, ColX = 15, ColY = 25, ColZ = 35
```

Comment: this doesn't actually give a new datatable, and yet is the accepted answer, when there was already an answer present that did exactly this, and stored the result in a datatable. that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by, assuming table1 and table2 are your two datatables, and resultTable is the DataTable you wish to populate with the results of the join. 
Also you can use union all operator.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this, assuming `table1` and `table2` are your two datatables, and `resultTable` is the `DataTable` you wish to populate with the results of the join:

```
var res = from dr1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
            join dr2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
              on dr1.Field<int>("ID") equals dr2.Field<int>("ID")
          select resultTable.LoadDataRow(new object[]
          {
            dr1.Field<int>("ID"),
            dr1.Field<string>("column name .. "),
            ... 
            dr2.Field<string>("column from table 2 .. "),
            ...
           }, false);
```

and `resultTable` will then be populated with the rows with the fields you've chosen in the select.

Comment: resultTable is not actually populated here though...i had to add a `dt = res.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();`

Answer (score 1):

Write a SQL SELECT statement that references tables in both of the databases, using a `JOIN`, assign aliases to the tables in the query, and then qualify the column references with the alias.

And use appropriate expressions in the SELECT list to return the resultset you want to return.

To emulate a "full outer" join, you may need to use a query with a `LEFT JOIN`, and another query with an ant-join, and combine the results with a `UNION ALL` operator.

Once you have a SELECT that returns the results you want, you can use that in an `INSERT .. SELECT` statement to save the results to another table.

---

That's about as specific as we can be, without more specific information, beyond a vague description of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Write a SQL SELECT statement that references tables in both of the databases, using a JOIN, assign aliases to the tables in the query, and then qualify the column references with the alias.

And use appropriate expressions in the SELECT list to return the resultset you want to return.